# How to align Icon with select control using Material design?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am new to Material design UI components and struggling with real basic alignment question.

I have a select control that uses an Icon for the drop down and then right next to this, another Icon to cancel the action.

Here is  all that is in render() part of page:

```
             <div style={{display:'flex', alignContent:'center'}}>
            <Select  IconComponent={ArrowDropDownCircleOutlined}  disableUnderline={true} 
                      renderValue={() => { return ('') }}>
                                <MenuItem value={'contains'}>Contains</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={'startswith'}>Starts with</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={'EqualTo'}>Equal to</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value={'isNull'}>is Null</MenuItem></Select>

                             <CancelOutlined onClick={() => console.log('hello world')} />
        </div>
```

this is what's displayed:

[image]
I have tried various style changes, verticalAlign:'middle", 'top', 'buttom', etc..but nothing aligns them.

If I change the select component to just an Icon, the two icons are aligned correctly however.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of alignContent: 'center' use alignItems: 'center'.
Here's a demo where it works:

[image: Edit align Icon with select control using Material design]

Comment: I'm now confused. I can see your demo/example working...however, when I use the EXACT same code in my system, it doesn't render in alignment?? I brought up the same page in IE just to see if it's some caching issue, and it doesn't align there either.

Comment: Instead of div with inline style try to use <Grid container alignItems="center"> ... </Grid>. Is this the only piece of code? Or is it inside some other component?

Comment: Thx, i'll give it a shot in a bit. For now, I've removed the Material UI framework and am sticking with semantic framework as I have not run into issues like this.